# How to create JSON from inputs name and value pairs

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working on my personal project and I need a little help. I have a table with some inputs which have `name` and `value` attributes. The problem is that I need to create a JSON with pairs `name`:`value`.
How do I do something like that with vanilla JS?

My code to print what I have:

```js
// Get all inputs from table and print name and value
document.querySelectorAll("table input").forEach((e) => {
    console.log(e.name, e.value);
});
```

What I need:

```json
{
  name1: value1,
  name2: value2,
  name3: value3,
  name4: value4,
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start out with an empty object and then, when you're iterating over the inputs, just assign a new key value pair for that object.

```js
const obj = {}

// Get all inputs from table and print name and value
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((e) => {
  obj[e.name] = e.value
})

console.log(obj)
```

```html
<input name="foo" value="foo">
<input name="bar" value="bar">
```

Use `JSON.stringify(obj)` to convert it in to a `JSON` string if needed.